# Inverse Laplace Transform of $F(s) = \frac{3s+8}{(s^2+2s+20)^2}$

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

Having a little trouble solving this fractional inverse Laplace were the den. is a irreducible repeated factor

$$F(s) = \frac{3s+8}{(s^2+2s+20)^2}$$

tried to apply partial fractions to it and i just get to the same result as F(S), rewriting the den as $s^4+4 s^3+44 s^2+80 s+400$ didn't help much either

Its driving me crazy its the last one i need to complete a test. In my class we haven't got to convolution yet, but a friend told me that i should try that, id appreciate if you guys help me with that by any possible method.

EDIT:

got to $$F(s) = \frac{3s+8}{(s^2+2s+20)^2}= \frac{3(s-1)}{((s+1)^2+19)^2}+ \frac {11}{((s+1)^2+19)^2}$$

using lineality:

$$ 3\times\left(\\{L^{-1}} \frac{(s-1)}{((s+1)^2+19)^2}\right)+11\times\left(\\{L^{-1}} \frac{1}{((s+1)^2+19)^2}\right) $$

im kinda new at this, i dont know what happens that the ecuation doesnt stay put in one line, but i think its understanadable

Comment: Do you mean $(3s+8)/(s^2+2s+20)^2$? Or do we have two parts, $3s$ and $8/(s^2+2s+20)^2$ to work with?

Comment: the first one srry about that

Comment: @Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ hello, can you take a look at my edit, you kinda gaved me that hint i would like to see if i proceeded well and how i can continue, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Using  [this](http://planetmath.org/inverselaplacetransformofderivatives),
$$L^{-1}F'(s)=-t\cdot f(t)$$

Let $$\dfrac{d\left(\dfrac{as+b}{s^2+2s+20}\right)}{ds}=\dfrac{3s+8}{(s^2+2s+20)^2}$$

Find $a,b$

Now use [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html), $$A\cdot L^{-1}\dfrac{s-a}{(s-a)^2+b^2}+B\cdot L^{-1}\dfrac b{(s-a)^2+b^2}=A\cdot  e^{at}\cos bt+B\cdot  e^{at}\sin bt$$

Comment: @ItaloCampoliDiIura, I meant the table of formulae.

Comment: ammm i see now i got it, but then, i must fin a,b using partial fractions right? i would like to see that process too since i did it like 3 times already but maybe im doing it wrong because it doesnt give me the desire expresion :S

Comment: i went for completing the square inside the parentesis and got to a similar expresión of those at the table, i just need to rework them as S - a to do the trick and solve them, that would be ok to do too?